# what is the best implementation of a delete method for two popups, using Mat-Dialog in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am implementing a dialog that will open a pop up asking if the user wanto to delete and imediatly the next step is ask for a comment.

For the first one (ask if want to delete), the code was good. I used the same method to implement this in cascade, but the files are not being deleted.

This is the code:

```
deleteRow(i: any) {
        this.dialogService
        .openConfigDialog('Are you really want to delete this file ?')
        .afterClosed()
        .subscribe(async (res) => {
            if (res) {
                
                /* this.reason
                    .openReasonDialog("Please describe the reason for delete")
                    .afterClosed()
                    .subscribe(async (res) => {
                        if (res) { */

                                let deleteRowRequest = {
                                    IstValues: [this.dataSource.data[i]]
                                };
                                this.istManagementService.deleteRecord(this.inputTable, deleteRowRequest).subscribe(
                                    (res: any) => {
                                        this.dataSource.data.splice(i, 1);
                                        this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
                                    }
                                )
                                    
                            /* }}) */
                            
                }
            }
    )
    }
                
                refresh(): void { window.location.reload()}
```

If I comment out, the files are deleted. If I do not comment, they are not deleted.

Comment: Interesting...  I did a quick test and was able to get a combination to work in a similar way.  Mine are slightly different in that they are components but they basically do the same thing.  Any chance that your 2nd (res) isn't returning true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to share all code because my dialogs are in a library and they are called by a service, but what I did to do a quick test it was this.

```
dialogNotify() {
    let data2: IDialogNotify = {
      title: 'Toolbar Menu',
      warning: 'Toolbar Menu',
      message1: 'The menu toolbar will show...',
      message2: 'NOTICE - When making changes to blah blah.' +
        '  ... depending on the processing power of your device.  Check the Messages indicator on the top right' +
        ' of the screen.',
      confirmButton: 'Ok, I got it',
    };

    this.dialogService.openNotify(data2);
    this.dialogService.openNotifyConfirmed().subscribe((confirmed: any) => {
      if (confirmed) {
        let data2: IDialogNotify = {
          title: 'Toolbar Menu',
          warning: 'Toolbar Menu',
          message1: "error",
          message2: "",
          confirmButton: 'Ok, I got it',
        };

        this.dialogService.openNotify(data2);
        this.dialogService.openNotifyConfirmed().subscribe((confirmed: any) => {
          if (confirmed) {
            this.logger.info('Confirmed: nested dialog');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Not sure if that helps you, but it did work. Are you sure that you are getting a true value for the 2nd one?

Answer (score 0):

I had put the (click) close at the same line of the dialog close.

After relocate to the close window, it solved my issue.